# Can I have application listening in multiple ports? (one for public and one for private use)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, iis, port

I have a `.NET MVC` application which has multiple features.

Can I host this application in `IIS` as single application by configuring different ports as shown below?

1. ```
   Website to view product              localhost:80/index.cs
   ```
2. ```
   API exposed for internal usage       localhost:23004/Listporducts();
   ```

Is it possible?

**Real time scenario**:  I am hosting application in `Azure` IaaS VM. My internal applications will use the `API` and customers shall use public `website`

Comment: Do you mean the Website and the API are inside the same application and you want just 23004 port could access the web api?

Comment: Yes, Website and the API are inside the same application.  I want port 23004 (or any other port) access the web API.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most easily thing is you could prevent the Azure VM's not open the 23004 port.  Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

If you don't want to use Azure MV, you could consider using a custom filter Attribute in the web api to check if the request is local. If the request is not sent from local, then you could directly return the 404 not found error.

More details about how to use custom Filter Attribute, you could refer to this [article](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/web-api-filters#:%7E:text=Filters%20can%20be%20used%20to,one%20or%20more%20action%20methods.).

```
public class CustomActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter { 
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { 
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal) { 
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult(); 
        } 
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { 
        // not yet implemented 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to open the port 23004 for internal azure services. So I can not block at NSG level.  [Internal service like Azure Functions]